# AspectJ: annotation-based logging aspect is not working in Spring Boot using compile-time weaving

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj

In my project I use some aspects as part of my project and some as part of a common library. The first request takes about 10 seconds with the default weaving concept of *Spring Boot*. Thus, we try to switch to CTW (compile time weaving) using *aspectj-maven-plugin 1.7*.

Start-up time has been reduced now, an aspect with pointcut

```java
@Around("execution(public com.XXXX.XXXXX.common.XXXX.APIErrorResponse *(..))")
```

is working, but the aspect with pointcut

```java
@Around("@annotation(com.xxxxxx.XXX.common.xxx.Loggable)"))
```

is not working (I have created a `@Loggable` annotation to apply entry/exit logging). I get the following compiler message:

```
[WARNING] advice defined in com.xx.xx.xx.xx.LoggerAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
```

I use the following configuration in my *pom.xml*:

*Editor's remark: missing information about pom.xml should go here.*

I use *ajc* 1.8.1 and compliance level 1.8.

My Loggable annotation:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface Loggable {}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us `Loggable` annotation and an example of this annotation in your code base.

Comment: Here is the annotation class            @Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface Loggable {

} It tried both retentionPolicy class as well as Runtime.

Comment: Please update your question as pasting code in a comment is not super readable.

Answer (score 0):

The warning means that the fully qualified package & class name in your pointcut does not exactly match the real one in your annotation.